# python how can i add new data into iptools IpRangeList

Tags: python, list, ip, range

recently , i find the python library "iptools" can help me to solve some problem , 
but i meet a problem in iptools.IpRangeList , 
i only can declare the initial data in first , like

```
internalIP = iptools.IpRangeList(
'127.0.0.1/8',                
'192.168/16',               
'10.0.0.1/8'
```

)

if i want to add a new ip into IpRangeList , compiler always show error

```
internalIP.append('1.1.1.1')
AttributeError: 'IpRangeList' object has no attribute 'append'
```

or openfrom file

```
intranetlist = IpRangeList()
if os.path.isfile("/tmp/intranal.list"):
    fp = open("/tmp/intranal.list", 'r')
    intranetlist = ([line.strip() for line in fp])        
    print intranetlist , len(intranetlist)
    fp.close()
    return
```

Result : 
['127.0.0.1/8', '192.168/16', '10.0.0.0/8'] 3

it is incorrect , the correct result is as below

```
>>> from iptools import *
>>> a=IpRangeList('127.0.0.1/8' , '192.168/16', '10.0.0.0/8')
>>> print a
(('127.0.0.0', '127.255.255.255'), ('192.168.0.0', '192.168.255.255'), ('10.0.0.0', '10.255.255.255'))
>>> len(a)
33619968
>>>
```

can anyone help me to solve this problem ? 
or have other library i can use for ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving that `AttributeError` because the `IpRangeList` object doesn't have an `append` method defined. Plus, internally it [defines the IP listing as a tuple](http://python-iptools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/iptools.html#IpRangeList) which you can't append to.

What you can do however is create a complete list of the IP ranges you want and then create the `IpRangeList` from that [using `*args` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters) to unpack the list into the function call, like so:

```
intranetlist = None
if os.path.isfile("/tmp/internal.list"):
    fp = open("/tmp/internal.list", 'r')
    intranetlist = IpRangeList(*[line.strip() for line in fp])
    print intranetlist , len(intranetlist)
    fp.close()
return intranetlist
```

As for appending to an already existing `IpRangeList`, that won't be possible without changing it, nor does it look like you can easily access the list of IPs once you've created an `IpRangeList`. So I'd suggest creating a basic Python list and creating the `IpRangeList` at the last possible moment, because they are effectively immutable.

Comment: hi Lego , i have another problem , how can i fast to convert like 127.1.1.1 to '127.1.1.1 , when i get a ip address , and it will be like 127.1.1.1 , but i need convert it to '127.1.1.1' to use in IpRangeList, or will show error , can you help me ? thanks.
>>> a=IpRangeList('127.0.0.1/8' , '192.168/16', '10.0.0.0/8')
>>> 127.1.1.1 in a
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    127.1.1.1 in a
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> '127.1.1.1' in a
True
>>> str(127.1.1.1) in a
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    str(127.1.1.1) in a
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I'd recommend openning a new question so the error can be formatted correctly.

Comment: hi Lego , i raise a new question . please help to review it , thakns  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668598/python-input-format-type-error-in-iptool-iprangelist